# Wrong namespace definition order with lxml

Tags: python, xsd, lxml, xsd-validation

I am creating a xml document, and I have this:

```
root=etree.Element("Element1")
NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
location_attribute = '{%s}noNameSpaceSchemaLocation' % NS
root.set(location_attribute, "Schema.xsd")
```

And I get this:

```
<Element1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNameSpaceSchemaLocation="Schema.xsd">
```

But what I need is the reverse:

```
<Element1 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Schema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Do you know if is this possible with lxml?

Comment: Considering XML both tags are considered equal. The order of attributes is not significant.

Comment: Why do you believe you need the attributes in a particular order?  Is it because you have non-XML software downstream, which consumes the XML put is not able to deal with variable order in attributes?  (In that case, many here will say "Get some better downstream software.")  Or is there another reason ... ?

Comment: I know order is not significant, but I have to send a XML file to an official web application and they reject my files if I don't invert the order of these attributes. I know is not standard and probably they are not using a proper XML downstream software...